# How to split a RichTextBox , and retain values in an array as integer values

Tags: c#, arrays

First of all,sorry for my bad english , i'm still learning.Now let's go back to my problem:
-I have a RichTextBox,where i introduce values like:
4112
3125
780
5680 etc.
-every value has a new line.What i mean is , after i introduce a value,i press ENTER.
All i want is,to save this values in an array,but as integer elements,not characters.How can I do that?
I tried with SplitChar method,but i don't understand this method,because i'm beginner in C#.
My try:

```
public void ViewMyTextBoxContents(){

//Create a string array and store the contents of the Lines property.
string[] tempArray = RichTextBox1.Lines;

// Loop through the array and send the contents of the array to debug window. 
for(int counter=0; counter < tempArray.Length;counter++)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(tempArray[counter]);
} }
```

But still,not working ..Thanks for help!!!Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = richTextBox1.Lines.Select(x => Int32.Parse(x)).ToArray();
```

Basically, you're missing the `Int32.Parse(tempArray[counter])` part. This parses the string to an int.

Adapting your code to do the same:

```
string[] tempArray = richTextBox1.Lines;

int[] resultArr = new int[tempArray.Length];
for (int counter = 0; counter < tempArray.Length; counter++)
{
    resultArr[counter] = Int32.Parse(tempArray[counter]);
}
```